# Posing XML string as parameter via cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to post a xml string to a remote perl script via cURL.  I want the xml string to be posted as a post parameter 'myxml'. See the code I am using below:

```
$url = 'http://myurl.com/cgi-bin/admin/xml/xml_append_list_init.pl';
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
        <SUB_appendlist>
          <SUB_user>username</SUB_user>
          <SUB_pass>password</SUB_pass>
          <list_id>129</list_id>
          <append>
            <subscriber>
              <address>test@test.comk</address>
              <first_name>Test</first_name>
              <last_name>Test</last_name>
            </subscriber>
          </append>
        </SUB_appendlist>';

$ch = curl_init(); //initiate the curl session 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); //set to url to post to
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // tell curl to return data in a variable 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml", "Content-length: ".strlen($xml))); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'myxml='.urlencode($xml)); // post the xml 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, (int)30); // set timeout in seconds 

$xmlResponse = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close ($ch);
```

However the remote server is not seeing the data in the 'myxml' parameter.  And I get the following response back in $xmlResponse

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 15 Apr 2011 12:00:44 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

I'm not a cURL expert by any measure so I may be doing something in mu cURL request which is obviously wrong.  Would appreciate it if anyone can shed any light or spot any problems in this.  Hope that is enough information.

Cheers,
Adrian.

Answer (score 1):

The body of your message is not text/xml data. It is application/x-www-form-urlencoded data. You have form data containing XML, not plain XML.

Your problem is akin to trying to open MyDoc.zip in MS Word. You have to deal with it as a zip file before dealing with it as Word.

Based on my reading of the PHP manual, you want to **remove**:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml", "Content-length: ".strlen($xml)));
```

and change the POSTFIELDS line to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'myxml' => $xml
));
```

Comment: Thanks.  Tried this removing the httpheader line and updating the postfields to take an array and the guys on the remote server say that the post variable is empty and Apache says invalid content length.

Comment: Making those modifications, changing the URI to one on my server that does a `print_r($_POST)` outputs `Array
(
    [myxml] => <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>` which is what I'd expect.

Comment: If I do a print_r($_POST) I only get the original contents of what I posted Array ( [subscriber_email] => adrian.walls@gmail.com [city_id] => 1 ), should this be updated with the cURL post data

Comment: My print_r statement is in the script I changed http://myurl.com/cgi-bin/admin/xml/xml_append_list_init.pl to point to (I also added `print $xmlResponse;` to the client script so I could see the output).

Answer (score -1):

That is not the correct content type for all browsers.

see [this article](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/381.cfm)

sometimes the content type for xml is:  `application/rss+xml`

Comment: `text/xml` is a perfectly fine Content-type for XML files (at least those which are intended to be human readable). `application/rss+xml` is how you should be more specific for RSS files… which the data in the question clearly is not.